# How to set secure flag on cookie programatically

Tags: java, security, servlets, cookies, servlet-3.0

I know we can do something like this:

```
<session-config>
 <cookie-config>
 <secure>true</secure>
 </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

But what I want to achieve is to set this flag (true or false) based on some config.

Should we use a filter and how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are in a servlet 3.0+ environment, and you don't want to use `web.xml` to specify the cookie-secure-flag but set it programmatically:

Implement a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it in the `web.xml` or via annotation.
In its `contextInitialized` method evaluate your secure flag from your config and set it on the `SessionCookieConfig`:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     boolean secure = ...
     sce.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(secure);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve within this method the http protocol used so that I can set the secure when it's HTTPS ?

Comment: @kkung this is a container specific config. Actually I don't know if this information is available during initialization of the context via the servlet api.

Comment: @kkung did you ever find a solution to your question re: retrieving within the contextInitialized method the http protocol used?  I need to do the same thing.